# Pipe streaming video from FFMPEG into OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, video, ffmpeg, rtp

I am using a Logitech C920 webcam with the beaglebone black running debian. I have successfully written an OpenCV python script that allows me get video from the camera and track objects. Unfortunately, the resolution, FPS, and overall video quality are poor using this method. I have found the proper code that allows me to utilize the webcam's H264 feature outside of OpenCV.

I've been trying to figure out how to pipe the output from ffmpeg INTO openCV so that I can utilize the camera's H264 capabilities as my video input for my OpenCV script. My commands look like this:

> ./capture -F -o -c0|avconv -re -i - -vcodec copy -f  rtp rtp://192.168.7.1:1234/|python camera.py

The first part of the pipe is using the linux v4l2 program that allows me to utilize my camera's H264 capabilities. The output from that is then fed to ffmpeg and then streamed to RTP. I want to retrieve the RTP stream in my OpenCV script but I haven't had success in getting it to work. Would I initialize something like the following in my script:

> capture = VideoCapture("rtp://192.168.7.1:1234/")

Please let me know if I am even going about this the right way. Is there a way to capture the stream directly from ffmpeg instead of streaming to RTP? Any suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You can call directly `capture = VideoCapture(#)` where `#` is the webcam device number. Typically 0 if you have just one webcam